# In C, How do I use specifier tags to input the "string" contents of a variable into a file name to make dynamic file names

Tags: c

I am making a program that custom writes a choose your own adventure style story in the Console but also writes it to a .txt file. The user will input their name into a variable with scanf(). When I use fopen() and name the file I want to use a format specifier with the variable containing their name along with the words ("%s'sAwesomeAdventure.txt, nameVariable), the same way its used in printf(). At least that is what I would like to do, but I cant do, does anyone know what I might do? Please for your help, and thank you very much.

I have tried;
1) the rename() function>>same result, which is no result
2) combining the whole string in a variable and then just putting the variable in the fopen() function with the mode specifier>>no go, but I might have missed something here. I miss the obvious things quite often.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

char nameVariable[] =("Rick");

   FILE * fp;

//as you can see here this is not correct on the following line
   fp = fopen ("%ssAwesomeAdventure.txt", nameVariable,  "w+"); 

   fprintf(fp, "Be excellent to eachother!");

   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
}
```

The file should be named: RicksAwesomeAdventure.txt

Comment: Build the string with `sprintf`

Comment: "*combining the whole string in a variable and then just putting the variable in the fopen() function with the mode specifier*" is the right way, but you need to show your actual code if you want us to figure out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mr. William Pursell. You guided me correctly with sprintf() and this is the result I was looking for.

## include

int main () {

```
char nameVariable[50];
char nameQuestion[] = ("What is Your Name?\n");
char customFileName[80];

printf(nameQuestion);
scanf("%s", nameVariable);

sprintf(customFileName, "%ssAwesomeAdventure.txt", nameVariable);

FILE * fp;
fp = fopen (customFileName, "w+");
fprintf(fp, "Be excellent to eachother!");
fclose(fp);

return(0);
```

}